# How to perform face detection in native c++ using the Google mobile vision API?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I'm using the [Google mobile vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision) (`com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3`) for [face tracking](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker) on live camera preview in my app (Android studio / Java), All the tracking process works well. But i want to draw stickers on detected face landmarks, and for that i need to increase the speed of the detection process, the current speed i have is not bad (11 FPS), but definitely can be better. When face are moved on the camera preview the drawings are not moved immediately with the face, I want to eliminate this delay by increasing the speed of the detection.

I use the following configuration for the `FaceDetector`:

`FaceDetector.FAST_MODE`, `FaceDetector.NO_CLASSIFICATIONS`, `FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS`.

So what i want to ask is: Is there a way to pass the face detector and the camera preview frames to native c++ function and perform the face tracking using native c++? I think the execution in native c++ code will be much faster, Tell me if I'm wrong. (I already have android NDK / JNI fully configured in my project so you can skip the setup part in your answer).

**Note:**

I saw many articles about OpenCV and it's native libraries, I **don't** and **will not** use OpenCV. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just because it has a Java API doesn't mean that it does all its internal processing in Java. I'd be surprised if Google's face detection library isn't already performing its most computationally intensive work using native code (or possibly even on the GPU on some devices).

Comment: @Michael Yes, I just asked how to use it in native c++.